# How to calculate power consumption from battery stats

Tags: arch-linux, python, battery

I set up the `arch` linux on my new `msi prestige ps42` laptop. To my disappointment, the battery life pretty much quickly deteriorated. After first 2 months of usage, the battery could supply the laptop for only about 3 hours.

Naturally I wanted to calculute what is the actual power consumption. For that purpose I recorded the battery stats in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` with a Python daemon. The main loop goes like this:

```
with open('/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/current_now', 'r') as curFile:
    current = float(curFile.read().replace('\n', ''))
with open('/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_now', 'r') as volFile:
    voltage = float(volFile.read().replace('\n', ''))
with open('/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now', 'r') as charNowFile:
    chargeNow = float(charNowFile.read().replace('\n', ''))
timeNow = time.time()
# time|power|energy
print(timeNow - startTime, current*voltage*1e-12, chargeNow*voltage*1e-12)
time.sleep(1)
```

The power was calculated as `voltage*current` (the `power_now` file was missing in the folder) and multiplied by `1e-12` as those data should be with `micro` units. The energy was calculated as `voltage*charge` and multiplied by `1e-12` as well. The time was recorded in `seconds`.

As a result I got something like this (time|power|energy):

```
0.0001957416534423828 7.868766 38.895102
1.1173264980316162 9.038664 38.895102
2.2340087890625 9.039228 38.897529
3.350689172744751 8.526364 38.897529
4.46724009513855 8.522639999999999 38.880539999999996
5.583956003189087 8.535461999999999 38.865978
6.69666862487793 10.040778 38.865978
7.810216903686523 9.999395999999999 38.705796
8.811989784240723 9.999395999999999 38.705796
9.81338357925415 8.591463 38.829572999999996
10.815097093582153 8.591463 38.829572999999996
...
```

Next I calculated the energy dependence from the power:

```
calcEArray = np.empty(0, float)
calcEArray = np.append(calcEArray, array[0,2])
for prevStat, nextStat in zip(array[:-1], array[1:]):
    calcEArray = np.append(calcEArray, calcEArray[-1] - (nextStat[0]-prevStat[0])*prevStat[1])
```

As the code indicates: `E_i = E_(i-1) - (time_i - time_(i-1))*power_(i-1)`

When I compared the calculated vs recorded energy, I got totally different curves:
[image]

The first idea is obviously the units are wrong, but I tried all combinations of 10eX units for both power and energy and the curves just won't match.

The second idea is the time span is too big and the power spikes are not recorded.

**Do you have any experience with recording power consumption like this?**

Comment: What are your laptop's specs? Most importantly, do you have an onboard and a dedicated graphics card? This sort of thing is often caused by Linux constantly using the dedicated card and never switching to the onboard one.  I can't find a "lenovo prestige ps42" did you mean ["MSI prestige ps42"](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/PS42-8RX)?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you plotting as "recorded"? The graph you show suggests it has a costant value of 0. Do the raw data have values that are non-0?

Comment: Sorry for typo, of course it is `MSI Prestige PS42` (more specifically `PS42 Modern 8MO`). It has integrated `Intel UHD Graphics 620` GPU. Regarding the plot, `recorded` stands for `charge*voltage` values. The values are non-zero, but the y axis scale is too big.